How do you handle different types of responses in your chatbot with Spring AI?
How can we design a Spring AI chatbot to handle different types of responses in the same endpoint, without resorting to multiple if-else statements in the controller? What strategies, design patterns, or Spring features can we leverage to achieve this in an efficient and scalable manner?
i wat to design chatbot AI with spring AI

have you read [ask] ? I feel your question is too broad for SO.

As vague as it is currently asked you can just pass the question on to a LLM and let it do it's thing. It will be able to handle many kinds of questions. If you want an actually useful answer from SO you need to provide more detail in what ways the responses are supposed to be different.
